# Kwargs and class-based views in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I've searched SO and the Django doc and can't seem to be able to find this.  I'm extending the base functionality of the *django.contrib.comments* app to use the custom permission system that's in my webapp.  For the moderation actions, I'm attempting to use a class-based view to handle the basic querying of the comment and permission checking on it.  *("EComment" in this context is my "enhanced comment", inherited from the base django Comment model.)*

The problem I'm having is `comment_id` is a kwarg being passed in from the URL in the urls.py.  How do I retrieve this properly from a class-based view?

Right now, Django is throwing the error `TypeError: ModRestore() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`.  Code included below.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'restore/(?P<comment_id>.+)/$', ModRestore(), name='ecomments_restore'),
```

**views.py**

```
def ECommentModerationApiView(object):

    def comment_action(self, request, comment):
        """
        Called when the comment is present and the user is allowed to moderate.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __call__(self, request, comment_id):
        c = get_object_or_404(EComment, id=comment_id)
        if c.can_moderate(request.user):
            comment_action(request, c)
            return HttpResponse()
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied

def ModRestore(ECommentModerationApiView):
    def comment_action(self, request, comment):
        comment.is_removed = False
        comment.save()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not using a class-based view. You accidentally wrote `def` instead of `class`:

```
def ECommentModerationApiView(object):
...
def ModRestore(ECommentModerationApiView):
```

should probably be:

```
class ECommentModerationApiView(object):
...
class ModRestore(ECommentModerationApiView):
```

Answer (score 3):

also, your url pattern needs to look like:

```
url(r'restore/(?P<comment_id>.+)/$', ModRestore.as_view(), name='ecomments_restore'),
```